# How to run compliance check using ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that is designed to run a compliance on a firewall. However my knowledge of ansible does not extend to configuring variables and conditional statements ..

This is my current playbook:

```
---
- name: Juniper SRX configuration compliance checks 
  hosts: juniper
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Syslog server check
    junos_config:
      src: files/syslog_config
      comment: Appropriate Syslog server configured 
  - debug:
      var: task

  - name: print success
    debug:
      msg: Syslog server check - OK
    when: not {{ task.changed }}

  - name: print failed
    debug:
      msg: Syslog server check - failed
    when: "{{ task.changed }}"

  - name: Admin credentials 
    junos_config:
      src: files/admin_user
      comment: admin user created and confirmed 


  - name: NTP check 
    junos_config:
      src: files/NTP server
      comment: correct NTP server 

  - name: idle timeout check 
    junos_config:
      src: files/idle timeout
      comment: idle timeout confirmed
```

This is what I want to achieve:

• If the task ( Syslog server check) is run against the firewall and the output is similar to the content of files/syslog_config … A pass message( i.e This control Syslog server check has been marked as a PASS compliance check) should be printed out and hence captured by Splunk or Elasticsearch.

• However if the task ( Syslog server check) is run against the firewall and the output is different to the content of files/syslog_config . A failure message ( i.e This control Syslog server check has been marked as a Failure and the following lines of configuration is missing (set system syslog host 192.168.100.70 source-address "{{ inventory_hostname }}".) should be printed out and hence captured by Splunk / ELK.

• In some scenarios , ( Which is not part of the yaml file at the moment ) , the task ( i.e the control check ) might be a configuration line that needs to be absent from the firewall. In this case , a pass message would be printed out if not found.

What extra line of code  ( i.e conditionals statements ) do I need to add to the yaml file to make this work ?

The above playbook is my attempt but it does not work as expected.

Comment: 1) add `register: config_result` to your first task. 2) debug the registered var in the next task 3) run your playbook 4) edit your question and show us what the var looks like from your output

Comment: I have managed to get it resolved and it looks like this ...             https://github.com/gefela/ansible_junos/blob/master/junos_config.yml   ....      The only thing left is what module do I need to add to display the content of success and failures ?

Comment: This is how it looks like now https://github.com/gefela/ansible_junos/blob/master/junos_config.yml     What do I need to do to bring out contents of pass and failures ?